# Install .ipa to iPad with or without iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, installation, ipa

I have the `.ipa` from PhoneGap build and I need to test it. I got provisioning profile from Developer account.

So my question is: can I directly put my `.ipa` to iPad to install for testing, or do I have to follow some rules to install?

Comment: you can use TestFlight to install it using without itunes. 
Or just upload your ipa here - http://www.diawi.com. And type the generated link in safari of ur device and say install

Comment: Thanks @NSS. I could not get the itunes thing to get working after spending hours on it. diawi.com seems promising and the app is already in the installation process. Keeping my fingers crossed.

Comment: used http://diawi.com and it works great. Will be using it from now on.

Comment: A mac app is here which use `Dropbox` for distributing ipa http://tryappbox.com/

Comment: This did it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042508/over-the-air-ota-ios-ipa-file-distribution-for-public

Comment: Use http://buildtry.com upload the IPA file and share the link to testers! very simple

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes, you can install IPA in iPad, first you have to import that IPA to your itunes. Connect your iPad to iTunes then install application just by click on install and then sync.

Comment: I installed Windows 7 in VirtualBox, installed iTunes version 12. Then downloaded the ipa file ([in my case an old version of VLC](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=128241)) and dropped it on iTunes. Then to sync I had to drag and drop the app icon to my device (an old iPad) listed in my iTunes in my virtual Windows 7. Worked!! Thanks.

Comment: I heard iTunes 12.7 removed the apps section. Does this still work with the latest version of iTunes?

Comment: This is likley no longer the preferred method since iTunes is going to be gone soon.  The preferred method is to upload to diawi.com

Comment: @JennaSloan - indeed. I just downloaded 12.10 in order to install an old ipad app via iTunes and there's no apps section. I used the diawi site to attempt the installation.

Answer (score 96):

No need to bother with [iTunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) for sharing your adhoc builds. Just upload your ipa file to [diawi](http://diawi.com)
and after successful uploading you will get a link open the link in safari and you will be asked to install app. Tap on install and enjoy

Comment: a good option, when you get error while sending app via test flight.

Comment: This option also works even if you want to send ipa file for download. No need to attach them in mail. Users can download by opening link in browser.

Comment: "No provisioning profile found in the application bundle."

Comment: @FullDecent Please retry uploading your build again. Sometimes Diawi shows this error for no reason.

Comment: @fossilet What is the size of  your ipa file?

Comment: @पवन it's about 200 MB.

Comment: does it need device to be jailbroken?

Comment: @blackfyre No it does not require an iDevice to be jailbroken, but the device's UDID must be included in the provisioning profile which was used to prepare the build.

Comment: Got error while installing "Unable to Install <appname> Please try again later"

Comment: Has anyone validated this or recent versions? I tried and in the "open with" options, there isn't any option similar to an installer.

Answer (score 81):

In Xcode 5 open the organizer (Window > Organizer) and select "Devices" at the top. Your plugged in device should show up on the left hand side. Drag the IPA file over to that device.

In Xcode 6 and Xcode 7 open Devices (Window > Devices). Again your device should show up in the left hand column. Drag the IPA file to the list of apps underneath "Installed Apps".

For iOS 9 devices, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30726375/2544629) on how to get the app running after doing this.

Comment: Great solution. This is perfect when you don't want to have to sync iTunes or have to upload it to some 3rd party to just get it on a device. Spot on

Comment: In Xcode 11 it's Window > Devices and Simulators. Thanks for the workaround!

Answer (score 39):

There are four ways, all of which I tested:

- [Test flight](http://help.testflightapp.com/)
- Install from iTunes - Create .ipa as ad-hoc and normal sync with ipad & itunes.
- Or best way you can create a URL for install while creating ipa select as enterprise and create index file with plist. This will work with individual developer account too.
- [Diawi](http://www.diawi.com/)

Comment: Is option 3 still possible with individual developer account? I know it is with enterprise account still

Comment: Not that testflightapp.com is shut down as of Feb 26 2015.

Answer (score 22):

You can also checkout [ios-deploy](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy).

It is as simple as running `ios-deploy -b path/to/ipa/file`.

It even works with path/to/project.app, which should be in the same location if you are doing cordova/phonegap builds locally.

Cheers!

Comment: This one fast foward from Mac OS to iOS.

Answer (score 20):

You can install IPA using Xcode

- Open Xcode
- Select Window in Top Menu Bar & Select Devices & Simulators
- Drag and Drop your IPA in the Apps Section

[image]

This will install application on your device.

Answer (score 8):

In Xcode 8, with iPhone plugged in, open Window -> Devices.
In the left navigation, select the iPhone plugged in.
Click on the + symbol under Installed Apps.
Navigate to the ipa you want installed.
Select and click open to install app.

Answer (score 7):

You can create the ipa for ad hoc distribution and use [diawi](http://www.diawi.com) to create a link for the your ipad. You just upload the .ipa and the provisioning profile, then a link is generated and you can visit it from your ipad in order to install the app (if the provisioning profile is for development you have to add your ipad's UDID to it).

Answer (score 7):

You can add an IPA as new app from [Apple Configurator 2](https://support.apple.com/apple-configurator).

[image]

Comment: This should be default way without iTunes. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

iPhone doesn't allow to install an ipa directly, so provide a direct link to the ipa file is useless. That's why some people uses external services that provide a link or a qcode to install the ipa.

Another option, that nobody told in the other answers to this question and that it's completely independent from iTunes or any external service, is to create your own script that generates an installation link and automatically sends it to your mobile (for example by email). I created a such script for my personal use, that:

1. creates the html file;
2. creates the plist file;
3. copies ipa, html and plist files to my server;
4. sends me the link.

Because I work on Linux, I created a Bash script. You can use any other scripting language, but it's important to know what to put in the html and plist files.

This is the part of my script that generates the html and plist content. I hope that it's enough self-explanatory:

```
sha=`sha1sum ${ipa} | awk '{ print $1 }'`
output=${sha}-${AppName}-${version}.ipa
html=${sha}-${AppName}-${version}.html
plist=${sha}-${AppName}-${version}.plist

# Generates html
echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
 <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge,chrome=1\">
    <meta name=\"MobileOptimized\" content=\"width\" />
    <meta name=\"HandheldFriendly\" content=\"true\" />
    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\" />
    <meta http-equiv=\"cleartype\" content=\"on\" />
 <title>Install ${AppName} ${version}</title>
 </head>

 <body>
   <h1><a href=\"itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=${serverUrl}${plist}\">
     Install </a></h1>
 </body>

 </html>" > ${html}

# Generate plist
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">
<plist version=\"1.0\">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>${serverUrl}${output}</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>${serverUrl}Icon%402x.png</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>${serverUrl}Icon.png</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>${bundle}</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>${version}</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>${AppName}</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>" > ${plist}
```

For a simple example you can also see: https://github.com/Saleh7/ipa-install

Answer (score 5):

If your using the latest version of Itunes and there is no APP section Click on summary while the device is connected to you PC . Then Drag and drop the file onto the "on my device" section.

-see picture for illustration[image: Illustration]

Answer (score 3):

How about iPhone Configuration Utility?

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

> iPhone Configuration Utility lets you easily create, maintain, encrypt, and install configuration profiles, track and install provisioning profiles and authorized applications, and capture device information including console logs.

[image: Install ipa files using Iphone configuration utility]

Update:

> Apple Configurator replaces iPhone Configuration Utility. With the the release of iOS 8, iPhone Configuration Utility is no longer supported or available for download. https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/apple-configurator/id434433123

Answer (score 3):

Use iFunBox. It's free, Mac/Win compatible. Just make an ad hoc build and save somewhere. Install from [iFunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/). I load all my test ad hoc release builds on my devices for testing before release using this method. Who has time to fiddle around with iTunes?

Comment: with out apple id login can we do this

Answer (score 3):

There were 3 ways to do this:

**Method 1:** Using iTunes. Yes, you can install `.ipa` in iPad, first you have to import that `.ipa` to your iTunes. Connect your iPad to iTunes then install application just by click on Install and then Sync.

**Method 2:** [iFunbox](http://i-funbox.com/)

**Method 3:** [Diawi](http://www.diawi.com/)

Answer (score 3):

All of the other answers are either out of date or too much work where it doesn't need to be.  Upload your .IPA file to diawi.com then either scan the QR-Code and install, or email the link to the device you want to install the app to, or type the shortened URL into your Safari browser and install that way.

I needed to get an app installed into an older iOS device today and this method took me less than 2 minutes to complete start to finish.

```
 https://www.diawi.com/
```

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version of iOS share ipa through AirDroap from mac to iPhone. it will directly install in your iPhone.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to select Ad Hoc distribution method to be able to install it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you built the IPA using PhoneGap Build online you can download and install the IPA directly on your Ipad/Iphone by opening build.phonegap.com in Safari **on the device**, logging in and then clicking the iOS tab (the download ipa button). You will then be asked to install the app you built.

Direct link to this after logging in is: https://build.phonegap.com/apps/YOUR-BUILD-NUMBER/download/ios

Answer (score 2):

- Goto http://buildtry.com
- Upload .ipa (iOS) or .apk (Android) file
- Copy and Share the link with testers
- Open the link in iOS or Android device browser and click Install

Comment: The URL no longer maps to an active site (29 Sep 2019).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [HockeyApp](https://hockeyapp.net/features/distribution/) to distribute your .ipa, it will send a link to the app to the testers,  then the tester will be ableto install the ipa directly from their browser on the device once clicking on the link.

Comment: Is it required to add tester  udid's

Answer (score 2):

Since Apple released **iTunes 12**, you must use **Apple Configurator 2** app to install ipa in your iPhone and iPad.

Download from this link: 
https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12

Answer (score 2):

I try to face with these problems and I use : https://www.installonair.com . It's free and not have limit like diawi.

1. You need to add device UDID to apple developer account devices
   part.
2. Build your project and archieve it ad hoc with your certificate
3. Open that link and upload your ad hoc ipa file to website
4. Get qr code and link to download.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy
1- Visit to [appforshare.io](https://appforshare.io) or [diawi](https://diawi.com)
2- Drag and drop the .ipa or .apk file
3- You will an installable link shortly, just give that link to clients or anyone to install

Although [diawi](https://diawi.com) limits you in terms of build size or link expiry and [appforshare.io](https://appforshare.io) doesn't.

PS: Be sure that UDID of iPhone or iPad is added to that provisioning profile by which you have signed your .ipa

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the browser in Iphone/Ipad and type the URl where the IPA has been uploaded and can directly download it to your Iphone or Ipad and install and run it.... simple and sweet ;)

Comment: Redundant answer on an old post.

Comment: How? My iphone treats it like a zip and doesn't let me do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

**You can install your iOS app without iTunes, App store, or third party sites.**

When you build the archive in xcode you can select for adhoc distribution. xcode will bring you through a dialogue where you enter the URL location where your app will be along with the urls for a 57x57 pixel png and a 512x512 pixel png. It will create a bundle with your ipa and manifest.plist

Upload your ipa and the two png files whereever you plan to host them. It has to have an SSL certificate and be served over https. You may want to upload your manifest.plist there as well, but technically I'm pretty sure you can have it somewhere else.

Next, somewhere, in a text, or a webpage or email, or whereever share your link as:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://URL/path/manifest.plist">Download anchor text</a>
```

For a longer, better, more detailed answer click [here](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/05/14/how-to-share-ios-app-ipa-with-users-for-testing-using-dropbox-or-your-website/).

As I understand, if this is a dev app, only devices that have been added to your device profile in the app store will be able to install the app.

Answer (score 0):

Quite old, but inspired on A-Sharabiani achieved this avoiding iTunes with AppCenter. Just create new App, creat new Release uploading the .ipa, and finally scanning a QR with your device that redirects to download.

Yeah.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a Mac, you can use Apple Configurator 2 (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12).

This application is used to configure and install apps in any iOS device.

> Apple Configurator 2 makes it easy to deploy iPad, iPhone, iPod touch, and 
>   Apple TV devices in your school or business.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option I've seen is [appsend.dev](https://appsend.dev) - free, modern and clean alternative to diawi