# Upload ipa in google drive

Tags: ios, ipa, over-the-air

My requirement is, If I upload an ipa file in google drive or share point then the tester should be able to install the ipa in his device from drive with out using iTunes . Is it possible? I can achieve this by deploying the ipa, plist and index.html file in server. The test able to download it for testing.

Comment: Why don't you use TestFlight and diawi.com. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160285/install-ipa-to-ipad-with-or-without-itunes/21011862#21011862

Comment: I don't want to use third party sites and SDK...

Comment: You should try diawi.com it simplest to use, no registration or sign in is required just open the url in Safari on the device and it will install app on device. Considering Google Drive and Dropbox services are also third parties.

Comment: Google Drive is for an example but I can use my organization's drive right?...

Comment: @jailani If you have find any solution with your question using google drive please do share I have same requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [link](http://iosdevelopertips.com/xcode/distribute-ad-hoc-applications-over-the-air-ota.html) which describes the process of OTA distribution of ipa files. This link uses old version of Xcode but you can follow it in new Xcode versions as well.

Note: You need url in advance & web-server where you will upload the ipa . plist & html file. I think you can give try using Google Drive / Dropbox

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I referred this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276907/enterprise-app-deployment-doesnt-work-on-ios-7-1 In oldman's answer he replaces the dropbox link with another how can I find that link for google drive?

Comment: is an enterprise developer program absolutely necessary if i am planning to  distribute .ipa file for my application via google drive/dropbox ?

Answer (score -3):

Rather that using the google drive I will suggest you to use the TestFlight..
Go to testflight.com. Create an account. Its the simple and best way to even allow the clients and testers to install the app without using iTunes.

Comment: Before voting please let me know why this suggestion is wrong. Please add a comment.

Comment: He stated above that he did not want to use a third party service.