# Distributing iOS apps via google drive

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, ota

I have an iOS app ipa to be shared with tester. I tried OTA distribution via google drive by creating the manifest file and the html link to download and install the ipa. I followed the  SO link

[Upload ipa in google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400432/upload-ipa-in-google-drive).

But I am getting the error while installing the app as below.

```
[MIInstaller _extractPackageWithError:]: Failed to extract archive:
Error    Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=5 "Could not extract
archive" UserInfo=0x12fd434d0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x12fd49ba0 "The
operation couldn’t be completed. Undefined error: 0",
LegacyErrorString=PackageExtractionFailed, FunctionName=+[MIBOMWrapper
extractZipArchiveAtURL:toURL:withError:], SourceFileLine=145,
NSLocalizedDescription=Could not extract archive}
```

I am not sure what is causing this error. Please suggest

Comment: Why don't you use testflight for distribute app to testers? ???

Comment: Previously we used dropbox to distribute and it was working fine. Now we have company google drive.. so thought of hosting from it.

Comment: @krilak88 I have the same problem, but with dropbox, did you find a solution ?