# Download IPA / APK from Crashlytics

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ipa, crashlytics

I'm using Crashlytics to distribute an app for Beta testing.

While it is easy and convenient to install the app on devices from the Crashlytics app, I have not been able to figure out how I could download only the IPA from the Crashlytics server.

Background: I need to get the IPA / APK for automated testing. My test environment will re-sign the IPA to be able to install it to test devices, so going the Crashlytics app way doesn't work.

What I need would be a download link for the IPA / APK as it used to be available in TestFlight or Hockeyapp.

Comment: Hi Nachi, thanks for supporting my cause with Android power :)

Comment: Check out my answer, I have now provided you with a way to do what you asked for.

Comment: @CommaToast check out my upvote I gave you yesterday. You might also want to check my own answer that provides a similar way ...

Comment: This question seems to be interesting, is this still valid: can we use IPA/APK from Crashlytics file to use it as an automation build?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After poking around myself, it doesn't look like there is any way to pull an ipa or apk from Crashlytics Beta.

I would suggest using something like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or [Fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/beta-deployment/) to automate your build process and have it a) upload to Dropbox or somewhere you can easily refer to and b) upload automatically to Crashlytics for distribution.

The [gradle crashlytics plugin](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/388925-beta-distributions-with-gradle) provides a handy method to do this:

```
gradlew assembleDebug crashlyticsUploadDistributionDebug
```

Comment: Although not a direct answer, this is the most viable approach because it is cross-platform and easy to do if you are already building your artifact using a CI server.

Answer (score 18):

If you're using it with iOS, you can enable **Settings > Safari > Advanced > Web Console**, then look in the web inspector of the download link from the install page on iOS. It will look like this (I swapped in gobbledegook text for some parts):

```
<a class="primary-button js-install-button" href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.crashlytics.com%2Fprojects%2F2F2F2F2F2FF2F2F2%2Freleases%2F2200806%2Fdownload.plist%3Fdevice_id%2F2F2F2F%26device_token%234JH23L4KH234LK2J34H2LK34H2LK3J4H2LK3JH42L3K4JH23LK4JH2L3K4JH2L3K4JH2LKJ3H4%253D--2KJ3H4LK2J3H4L2KJ3H4LK2J3H4LK23JH4LK2J3H4L%26payload_token%2KL34JH2LK3JH4L2K3J4HL23KJ4HL23JK4" id="most-recent-install">Install</a>
```

Then just copy out the URL-encoded URL:

```
https%3A%2F%2Fapps.crashlytics.com%2Fprojects%2F2F2F2F2F2FF2F2F2%2Freleases%2F2200806%2Fdownload.plist%3Fdevice_id%2F2F2F2F%26device_token%234JH23L4KH234LK2J34H2LK34H2LK3J4H2LK3JH42L3K4JH23LK4JH2L3K4JH2L3K4JH2LKJ3H4%253D--2KJ3H4LK2J3H4L2KJ3H4LK2J3H4LK23JH4LK2J3H4L%26payload_token%2KL34JH2LK3JH4L2K3J4HL23KJ4HL23JK4
```

Then urldecode that on your command line using PHP:

```
php -r "echo urldecode('{PASTE THE ABOVE URL HERE}');"
```

(Make sure that you use double quotes around the PHP line, and single quotes around the URL.)

Then paste the URL-decoded result into Safari on your Mac. You'll see an XML file; copy the download link and paste into your browser. This will download the IPA to your Mac :D

Answer (score 11):

As far as I can see there is no straight forward way to download an IPA from Crashlytics.
However, if you really need to get the file it can be done.

- Copy the link target of the Install button in the Crashlytics mail (alternatively view source and copy from there, this is what I did)
- Paste to Safari in the Simulator. This will install the Crashlytics app in the simulator
- Open install page in the Crashlytics app in simulator
- inspect simulator with your Macs Safari (Develop > Simulator)
- Copy button link and open in Safari on Mac - there you go

Of course this is nothing you want to do as a standard procedure :)
And sorry this is iOS only, so no bounty for me :(

Answer (score 7):

I found an easy way to get APK builds on Android. Follow these steps:

1. Install "Amaze File Manager" on your device. Free version is enough and it doesn't need your device to be rooted.
2. Open "App Manager" in the menu on the left
3. Find your installed build by its name
4. Press "three dots" and select "backup"
5. You will find your APK file in the storage/emulated/0/app_backup

Answer (score 4):

This answer is probably too late, and is only specific to the APK file, but I did manage to identify where Crashlytics stores the APK before installation.

After installing Beta/Crashlytics on your device, go ahead and download your application, but don't install it - just leave it at the screen asking if you want to install (just in case Beta/Crashlytics deletes the APK after installation, not sure if they do though)

Then, using adb via another computer, identify the file name of your application by opening up a shell and finding all APK files.

1. Open command prompt or terminal, and run adb devices to ensure your device is recognized
2. Once recognized, run adb shell, and then type su to enter superuser mode
3. There are 2 ways - you can search for all APK files and look for a file name similar to what you would expect using "find / -iname *.apk" OR you can try listing the files sorted by modified date to look for a recently modified APK using the following command "ls -nl [directory] | sort -k 8,8n -k 6,6M" where [directory] is the directory you want to list
4. Note the location, and then exit adb, and grab the file using adb pull - in my case it was "adb pull /data/app/myapplication.apk"

TL;DR - Beta/Crashlytics downloads the APK file for your application to /data/app/ before installing.  You may need root privileges to access this folder.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This may specifically help those who are trying to retrieve the APK file.

If you're using Android, you can use Android Monitor to extract the file downloaded from the Crashlytics Beta app.
In order for this to work, you must have already installed the Crashlytics Beta app and have downloaded your app from within the Beta app.
Then, follow these steps:

1. Open Android Device Monitor
2. Select your device in the "Devices" tab on the left
3. Click on the "File Explorer" View on the right
4. Navigate through the path: `data/data/io.crash.air/files`.
   There you should find your .apk file
5. Click on the "Pull a file from the device" button in the top right.

Very complicated, but probably one of the few ways to extract it.

Another thought would be to use Wireshark to sniff the traffic when the device tries to download the APK/IPA file. This can be done while using an emulator.

Comment: Not able to open data/data/io.crash.air/files. It is just showing one data folder.Not able to go inside that folder

Comment: @ManojSoundarrajan Do you have access to that filepath? Maybe try running this on an emulator?

Answer (score -1):

I am using crashlytics for distributing app to testers, The steps are as

1. Install crashlytics(add fabric+crashlytics) to your code as described on their site.
2. Now, make archieve of your application.(Check that provisioning profile and signing identity, the udid of testers are added with provisioning profile).
3. Now, click on fabric symbol at right-top corner, click on distribute button on that.
4. Once you click on distribute, this will show textfield and add button to add email addresses of testers.
5. After adding testers email addresses click on next button and continue.

This will send email of ipa files to testers and show buttons to install it.
This is working fine will latest versions of iOS.

Comment: That's not the question, that's the obvious use case. What I (and some others) are looking for is a direct download link for the app. As described, I do not want to install the file.

Comment: oh sorry, misunderstood, They are not providing direct link for download, Yes you can forward your mail to other users, anyone can download from that. If you are really interested in getting link such a way than i can say that follow the steps as described by Razvan on link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042508/over-the-air-ota-ios-ipa-file-distribution-for-public for OTA distribution, and for creating ipa automatically use jenkins or make simple commanline script to create ipa file, and just hit that one in terminal

Comment: Application named Buildshake is currently under development which is going to be used for the same(from http://ngeleousera.com/)

Comment: Thanks, But that's not what I'm asking for. I also know other Beta distribution platforms that offer what I need.  But I want to know how this can be done with Crashlytics!

Comment: No, they are not allowing that, actually they are installing it via there own application that is getting installed on your device first.