# IPA app : Bundle not installed

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I created an app and I want to distribute it through an ipa file (I have to do that like this ...)

When I send the file to the user he can install the app but when he wants to open it, there is a message : **appName can't be download**

In the log I can see : **LaunchServices reports com.bundleID** is not installed.

I can install it on my iPhone but not on a external iphone. So i think there is a problem with the provisionning profile.

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong :/

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Have you got an Enterprise Apple Developer Id? I don't think it's possible to distribute .ipa files otherwise.

Comment: @Nick i have a apple dev id ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. You have two ways to send your app to other user -

1) From standard apple developer account: You have to register other users device UDID to the developer account -> Create the ipa with that provisioning profile and -> upload ipa to https://www.diawi.com/ and get a installation link -> Then Provide the same to other user

2) From enterprise apple developer account: You don't have to register the device UDID in enterprise account, just create a ipa using distribution certificate and provisioning profile -> upload ipa to https://www.diawi.com/ and get a installation link -> Then Provide the same to other user

See: [Over The Air (OTA) iOS IPA File Distribution For Public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042508/over-the-air-ota-ios-ipa-file-distribution-for-public)

or

http://martiancraft.com/blog/2017/02/creating-ios-app-download-pages/