# How to send iOS Unity games to Sponsor/Publisher

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, publish

I got a sponsor for my Unity Android/IOS game, I integrated Chartboost ads and google play services (Works for both android and IOS), Sending Android version was easy build APK and send,

But what about IOS, the Sponsor sent me a " **.mobileprovision** " and " **.cer** " files what to do with that ? basically how should I send him the IOS version of the game ?

I'm new to IOS development so be easy on me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign your IOS-Build with the given Certificate and the provisioning profile you got from your Sponsor. If you don't know how to build for IOS, the easiest way would be to use [Unity Cloud Build](https://build.cloud.unity3d.com/).  You need to [generate a p12 file from the ".cer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418661/how-to-create-p12-certificate-for-ios-distribution) you got from you sponsor.  Then you can use the p12 and the mobileprovision files to setup a IOS-buildtarget. => After the build is done you will get a link you can share with your sponsor.

Comment: Say @MariusJunak, can you locally push the build on to your own devices, when doing that?  I was in a similar situation - we've only ever before had total access to the iTunes account from clients. Thanks for the tip here

Comment: I haven't done this myself but you could try a solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160285/install-ipa-to-ipad-with-or-without-itunes)