# How do I install a React Native application on my device without the development server and debugging?

Tags: react-native

I would like to test performance so I do not want to use the development server or any development mode.  I just want to install the app to a physical device without going through the Google Play store or Apple.  How can I do that?

The [docs say that I should do this](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.19/docs/running-on-device-ios.html):

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output iOS/main.jsbundle
```

That gives me a file.  What do I do with that file to get it to my device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already built your APK\IPA:

For android you can run: adb install path\to\your\apk (add -r if you want to reinstall)

For ios I'm not sure, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20160285/) SO question might help:

> Yes, you can install IPA in iPad, first you have to import that IPA to your itunes. Connect your iPad to iTunes then install application just by click on install and then sync.